# Linq & C# - Inserting distinct data from one class into another

Tags: c#, linq

Afternoon all

I have a lovely webservice call that brings back a list, we'll call it `List<Everything>`

This would return something along the lines of:

```
Product ProductName SomethingElse
1           Dave    abc
1           Dave    def
1           Dave    ghi
2           Jason   abc
2           Jason   def
3           Terry   abc
3           Terry   def
3           Terry   ghi
3           Terry   jkl
```

I then have another `List<Products>` (int Product, string ProductName) that I would like to populate using the distinct product information in `List<Everything>`.

So I'm trying to get the following result:

```
Product Productname
1       Dave
2       Jason
3       Terry
```

How can I achieve this using Linq?

Apologies for what is probably bloody obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Products> products = (from x in everythingList
                          group x by new { x.Product, x.ProductName } into xg
                          select new Products
                          {
                             Product = xg.Key.Product,
                             ProductName = xg.Key.ProductName 
                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var distinctProducts = everything.Select(e=>new { Product, Productname = e.ProductName }).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Products> products = GetEverythingService()
 .Select(p => new Products { Product = p.Product, Productname = p.ProductName})
 .Distinct();
```

As rightly pointed out by dlev in the comments [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) will only work in this case if the Products class implements the [IEqualityComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface and overrides the Equals and GetHashCode methods.

This could be overkill if a comparison is only required in this one situation although if product object comparisons are to be carried out elsewhere using the id and product name then it is a viable option. I personally find it a bit more readable than the GroupBy Linq extension but obviously opinions will vary on this.

Comment: Unless `Products` overrides `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, this won't work.

Comment: @dlev - of course you are correct; I have amended the answer to highlight this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
List<Everything> items = ...

var results = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Product, x.ProductName })
                   .Select(g => new Products() 
                    { 
                       Product = g.Key.Product, 
                       ProductName = g.Key.ProductName 
                    })
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it like this.

```
List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
var listEverything = select d in "data from your ws"
                          select d.Product, d.ProductName).Distinct(x=>x.ProductName);
foreach(var item in listEverything)
{
products.Add(new Products { Product=item.Product, ProductName=item.ProductName});
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in another answer Distinct doesn't accept a lamba as a filter. It will accept a CustomComparer however.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var unique = list.GroupBy(item => item.Product)
                 .Select(group => new
                                  {
                                      Product = group.Key, 
                                      group.First().ProductName
                                  })
                 .ToList();
```